# LibreOffice 4.2 launch oddities in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

With the upgrade to 14.04, my LibreOffice launches became noticeably glitchy. With LibO 4.2.3.3, the menu bars would overlap for about 10secs, then the whole app would "grey out" for another 10secs or so. Subsequent launches were better, but the spinner would keep spinning for about 10secs+ after LibO opened.

It wasn't clear whether this was a LibO issue, or Ubuntu, since the two upgrades came at the same moment. The issue was partially resolved in [an AskLibreOffice Q&A](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/33517/libreoffice-423-very-slow-startup-on-ubuntu-1404/) by enabling "quick start".

Today I got the LibreOffice 4.2.4.2 update, and the first-time launch is very quick, but the lingering "busy pointer"/spinner issue continues. (Another user has [posted a video of this behaviour on YouTube](http://youtu.be/dabnfddx5xE).)

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? Any explanations or resolutions? Many thanks!

Comment: I have experienced the same behavior (regarding "busy pointer" when clicking on menus). I believe it's Unity menu integration issue and it exists from Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: It's definitely Unity... I installed GNOME shell under same other operating system elements, and no such problem anymore... I think I will switch to different Ubuntu-based distribution :)